# Sliding Current Carousel Item in Bootstrap Modal Slider

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am trying to create a simple lightbox using Bootstrap carousel and Modal. Please [take a look at sample file which I have here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/J8GLy/2/).

What I would like to do is starting the Modal Carousel as same slide (current slide) of the main carousel. As you can see from the example when I start the Modal it just start from the first item but I need to start from current active slide.

Can you please let me know how to do this?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well span9 columns">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <a href=".bell" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="bell" class="modal hide fade bell" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse"><a href=".bell" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-resize-full icon-white"></i></a>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thansk

Comment: please use only the 'twitter-bootstrap' tag for Twitter Bootstrap questions

Comment: so, do I have to edit the post now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
$('.bell').on('show', function() {
    var targetSlide = parseInt($('#myCarousel .active').index('#myCarousel .item'));
    $('#myCarousel2').carousel(targetSlide);
});
```

This gets the current index showing on the main carousel.

```
$('#myCarousel .active').index('#myCarousel .item')
```

This sets the current slide of the modal carousel.

```
$('#myCarousel2').carousel(/*Number here*/);
```

[Here is a jsFillde](http://jsfiddle.net/J8GLy/9/) with the above code.

Comment: Thanks Schmalzy, but it seems there are some issues with your solution as: When you slide the main slider to third item and then run the modal the modal carousel again starts from first slide and stops on second one also sometimes after re-opening the modal it doesn't work!

Comment: I updated it a little bit to solve the third-slide bug (See the same jsFiddle link), I added parseInt. but it still seems to brake after a while. I know I am on the right track with this... but there is something I am missing....

Comment: I think I figured it out.... the jsFiddle had an old version (2.0.2) of the bootstrap js file. I added a reference to the current version (2.3.2) and it works perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/J8GLy/9/

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your time. It works now, just the only minor issue is why the Modal slider is starting from previous slid? foe example when ever you click on slide 2 on main carousel it first displays the slide one and then stops on two! Is there any way to start it from exact slide? once again thanks for your help!

Comment: You can fix that by changing `$('.bell').on('shown', function() {` to `$('.bell').on('show', function() {` (changing `shown` to `show`). And no problem. I enjoy solving problems like this....